# Symfony CMF with multiple images on Product entity

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-cmf

I'm currently trying to make `Symfony CMF` and `Sonata` allow the admin user to add multiple images to a product through the same view panel. I have my `Product` and `Image` entities setup and working individually with their ORM relationships too.

Product:

```
class Product extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $images;

    // ...
```

Image:

```
class Image extends AbstractEntity
{    
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="image", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $product;

    // ...
```

Rather than having the user add all the images first and then link to them, I want it to be achievable from the same view. So in my `ProductAdmin` class I have added the following:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('Product')
            ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))

            // everything else ...

            ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'type_options' => array('delete' => false),
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
            ))
        ->end();
}
```

Currently this allows me to upload images from the product management page. However it does not create a link between the product and image and I'm not sure what I need to do to get it to do that.

**UPDATE**

Having read countless articles across StackOverflow and the wider web the common response I seem to be seeing is that the relation is only stored when the `sonata_type_collection` is used for the Admin page of the Entity which holds the relationship (in my case that would be the image). I can understand why it is that way, but it would be much better from a user perspective to work the other way round also (as I'd expect to add images to a product, and not add images and then add a product to them).

I'll leave this question open in case anyone has/does figure out a workaround.

**WORKING**

I've managed to get it working. Firstly I have changed my relationship to a Many-to-Many (so that images can be re-used for other products as my system contains versions), however I do not believe this is the fix itself, but worth noting none the less.

What I think has made it work is the inclusion of the `by_reference` attribute:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->with('Product')
            ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))

            // everything else ...

            ->add('images', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'type_options' => array('delete' => false),
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
            ))
        ->end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was because I was missing `'by_reference' => false`: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference

> Similarly, if you're using the collection form type where your underlying collection data is an object (like with Doctrine's ArrayCollection), then by_reference must be set to false if you need the adder and remover (e.g. addAuthor() and removeAuthor()) to be called.

Or in my case `addImage()` and `removeImage()`.